# Apex Class Creation to use in trigger

Tags: apex

How can I make a separate Apex class and method using this trigger?

```
Trigger contactFromAccounts on Account (after update) {
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (account a : trigger.new) {
        account old = trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        if (a.billingstreet != old.billingstreet|| a.billingcity !=old.billingcity || a.billingstate !=old.billingstate || a.billingcountry != old.billingcountry) {
            accountIds.add(a.Id);
        }
    }
    if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
        contact[] updates = [select Id, accountId from contact where accountId in :accountIds];
        for (contact c : updates) {
            account a = trigger.newmap.get(c.accountId);
            c.mailingStreet = a.billingStreet;
            c.mailingcity = a.billingcity;
            c.mailingstate = a.billingstate;
            c.mailingpostalcode = a.billingpostalcode;
            c.mailingcountry = a.billingcountry;
                    }
        update updates;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I want to create a separate apex class for this trigger, im kind a new in coding apex on salesforce. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you don't know how to create Apex classes, you should check out Trailhead, where there is great introductory content. See [Quick Start: Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-apex/quickstart-apex-1) and [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can drop what you have into a separate class method and it will work as written, since Trigger context variables are accessible from any context (they will just be null outside a trigger):

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler
{
    public static void updateContactAddresses()
    {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (account a : trigger.new) {
                account old = trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
                if (a.billingstreet != old.billingstreet|| a.billingcity !=old.billingcity || a.billingstate !=old.billingstate || a.billingcountry != old.billingcountry) {
                    accountIds.add(a.Id);
                }
            }
            if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
                contact[] updates = [select Id, accountId from contact where accountId in :accountIds];
                for (contact c : updates) {
                    account a = trigger.newmap.get(c.accountId);
                    c.mailingStreet = a.billingStreet;
                    c.mailingcity = a.billingcity;
                    c.mailingstate = a.billingstate;
                    c.mailingpostalcode = a.billingpostalcode;
                    c.mailingcountry = a.billingcountry;
                    }
        update updates;
    }
}

Trigger contactFromAccounts on Account (after update) {
    AccountTriggerHandler.updateContactAddresses();
}
```

However, it makes it much easier to test your methods if they do not rely on the trigger context variables, so a better version would look like this:

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler
{
    public static void updateContactAddresses(Map<ID, Account> updatedAccounts, Map<ID, Account> oldAccounts)
    {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (account a : updatedAccounts.values()) {
            account old = oldAccounts.get(a.Id);
            if (a.billingstreet != old.billingstreet|| a.billingcity !=old.billingcity || a.billingstate !=old.billingstate || a.billingcountry != old.billingcountry) {
                accountIds.add(a.Id);
            }
        }
        if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
            contact[] updates = [select Id, accountId from contact where accountId in :accountIds];
            for (contact c : updates) {
                account a = updatedAccounts.get(c.accountId);
                c.mailingStreet = a.billingStreet;
                c.mailingcity = a.billingcity;
                c.mailingstate = a.billingstate;
                c.mailingpostalcode = a.billingpostalcode;
                c.mailingcountry = a.billingcountry;
                }
            update updates;
      }
}

Trigger contactFromAccounts on Account (after update) {
    AccountTriggerHandler.updateContactAddresses(Trigger.NewMap, Trigger.OldMap);
}
```